# Adding msgbox if my pivot table has empty cells

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1mrq2.jpg)I have an Excel workbook that runs a macro and in the end displays everything in a pivot table

I am trying to add a msgbox when my pivot table has an empty cell (at the end of my macro)
I already did the conditional formatting version(color blank cells red) and it works fine, but the client wants a msgbox to alert him.

I found a IsEmpty command that should work but I cant seem to make it look only inside said pivot table.
Here is what I tried:

```
Sub IsEmpty()

If IsEmpty(ActiveSheet.Range("PivotTables(1)")) = True Then
    'Cell A2 is not blank
   MsgBox "Cell A2 is empty"
Else

End If
End Sub
```

I'm sure the way my If statement is written is false. Just cant seem to find the right syntax.

Thanks in advance

Picture added; I want the macro to target pivot's C column. However, you cant know which cell will be empty or how long the list will continue. 
And if just make Excel check a broad spectrum(c2:c300), there will always be en empty cell after the pivot table is finished.
There might be a loop you can create but its way over my current skill set.

The pivot table's name is "PivotTable2"

Is there a to search only in the pivot table's column c for empty cells?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please consider the capabilities of the function below. It will return True or False depending upon the count of items in columns A and C. In column A text, number or function is counted. In column C there must be a number in each cell. If both counts are the same the function returns True. Either count can be further refined if there are exceptions which the current function doesn't correction evaluate.

```
Function IsComplete() As Boolean
    ' 025

    Dim Rng As Range

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PivotTables(1)")      ' change to suit
        ' set a range from A3 to end of column A
        Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(3, "A"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
    End With

    With Application.WorksheetFunction
        IsComplete = (.CountA(Rng) = .Count(Rng.Offset(0, 2)))
    End With
End Function
```

You can use code to call this function and display a message box for True and another one if the function returns False. The code can be hitched to a button on your sheet, anywhere in your workbook.

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim Txt As String

    If IsComplete Then
        Txt = "The pivot table was created without mistakes."
    Else
        Txt = "Some data are missing in the pivot table."
    End If

    MsgBox Txt, vbInformation, "Action report"
End Sub
```

You can also call the function as a UDF and display True or False in a cell of any sheet in your workbook. The UDF call would be like `=IsComplete()`. You might also embed the UDF call in an IF condition and display another text on your worksheet.

```
=IF(IsComplete(),"All's well","Missing Item")
```

In fact, you could slightly modify the function to return the difference between one count and the other and display "1 item missing". The possibilities are endless because the function is so versatile.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Forgot to mention, i want to to search the whole column C, but if I change the "A2" to "A" it says: Application-defined or object-defined error.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Of course. There are in excess of 1.4 million cells in a column. Chances are overwhelming that some of them will be blank. Therefore the test may not be useful in any way. Try to use COUNTA() to test if the column has as many entries as you require.

Comment: The problem with "entries as you require" changes from uploaded data, which means the range also changes, and I'm back to the same problem. I need to look only in the pivot table. which is dynamic. I hope this makes sense :)

I just feel if only there was a way to search in the pivot table(have only one) it would be much easier to code.

Comment: It's possible to define a range in the pivot sheet if you know its name. It's possible to check if some cells in that sheet are empty if you know their address. I suggest that you post a picture of your pivot sheet and indicate the cells you want checked. If you can't pinpoint them, describe the way in which they might change. You can do this by editing your question.